# How do I pause my code until CAPTCHA is entered?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

[image]

I have managed to compile the below mentioned code, the code is working fine, but I need to pause the code from running until I enter CAPTCHA value and click proceed button.

How can it be achieved ?

I also want the continue the code after I click the proceed button and the next page is loaded.

I have also attached an Image for reference.

```
Sub TDS_Autofill()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp"
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set DOC = IE.document
DOC.parentWindow.execScript "sendRequest(281)", "JavaScript"

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("n2").Value = "Company" Then
DOC.getElementById("0020").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("n2").Value = "Non Company" Then
DOC.getElementById("0021").Click
End If



If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("p2").Value = "(200) TDS/TCS Payable by Taxpayer" Then
DOC.getElementById("200").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("p2").Value = "(400) TDS/TCS Regular Assessment" Then
DOC.getElementById("400").Click
End If


IE.document.querySelector("select.form-control").selectedIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("s2").Value
DOC.querySelector("#div_nature_error .form-control").FireEvent "onchange"



DOC.getElementById("NetBanking").Click

DOC.getElementById("NetBank_Name_c").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("u2").Value
DOC.querySelector("#NetBank_Name_c").FireEvent "onchange"


DOC.getElementsByName("TAN")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("b2").Value

IE.document.querySelector("select[name=AssessYear]").selectedIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("m2").Value


DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line1")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("c2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line2")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("d2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line3")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("e2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line4")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("f2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line5")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("g2").Value


IE.document.querySelector("select[name=Add_State]").selectedIndex = 21


DOC.getElementsByName("Add_PIN")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("i2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_EMAIL")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("j2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_MOBILE")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("K2").Value




DOC.querySelector("#Submit").Click





End Sub
```

Comment: It is possible but as you are trying to achieve the very thing that site is designed to protect against.. it's not advisable

Comment: No, I just need the code to pause untill I enter the Captcha by myself. That's it.

Comment: You could have 2 buttons in a form assigned to 2 UDF's. Press the first button to take you to the point where it enters the mobile number. Then enter what you need to and press the second button to complete the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an input box as this will pause code execution until an answer is submitted and could be used to enter the captcha without having to click on the website. The line below should work:

```
DOC.getElementsByName("captchaText")(0).Value = InputBox("Captcha:")
```

If you are on one monitor you will need to open excel on half and the website on the other half so that you can see what the captcha is while you enter it though.

Comment: @ArpitJain No problem